# Is it possible to view generated json from Azure CLI later?

Tags: azure

I'm learning Azure by following Plural-sight. Unfortunately, I'm experiencing tough time to progress with [this course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/developing-dotnet-microsoft-azure-getting-started-update/table-of-contents).

I'm learning - **how to crate app service**. Author created webapp to show demo. I'm following the video, and preparing notes simultaneously. Unfortunately, command line interface timeout occurred, and hence the generated json was gone.

Now, I need to know where can I get the json once again for my reference as I need this JSON to go ahead with my work. In fact, I need to know the value for `deploymentLocalUrl` key.

Since the app service was created successfully, I tried to get the required information from portal. With my existing knowledge, I almost verified all the tabs inside the **App Service**, but I could not get `deploymmentLocalUrl` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Export Template** option from the **Azure Portal** to save the template and create the App Service again whenever needed.

Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal) documentation on how to export the template.

Comment: Hi @Jagrati, Thank you for your answer. I'm searching for a way to find the value for the key `deploymentLocalGitUrl`. I followed your suggestion, but the generated file does not contain the information whatever I'm looking for. Hence, I compromised myself and deleted that resource to create once again.